# How to save data from notification received when the app is in the background

Tags: android, firebase, sqlite, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know how to save the information received from data payload of firebase cloud messaging.
What actually I want is, I am receiving the fields called notification_type and other stuff from data payload and I want to save it somewhere when the application is in the background and retrieve it when ever I open my application and update my UI based on that.

Till now I have tried saving it on Sharedprefrences, external file, and lastly on local db, all these worked fine and saved the data when the app was in the foreground, but they did not work when the app was in the background.

Below is the code that I tried recently, to save the data in the local db, works fine when the app is in the foreground, but does not work when the app is in the background.

**FireBaseMsgService.class**

```
public class FireBaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
     @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       // for normal notifications
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        if(remoteMessage.getData().get("Notification_type").equals("2")){
            String Org_Id=remoteMessage.getData().get("Org_Id");
            String Unit_Id=remoteMessage.getData().get("Unit_Id");
            String User_Id=remoteMessage.getData().get("User_Id");
            String PatientId=remoteMessage.getData().get("PatientId");
            String Notification_type=remoteMessage.getData().get("Notification_type");
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
                String Click_Action=remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
                User_Id=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTag();
                saveNotificationDataToDb(getApplicationContext(),Notification_type);
                FirebaseNotificationService firebaseNotificationService=new FirebaseNotificationService(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                        remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),
                        Click_Action,
                        User_Id,
                        Org_Id,
                        Unit_Id,
                        PatientId,
                        Notification_type);
                firebaseNotificationService.createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                        remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),
                        User_Id);
                BusProvider.postOnMain(BusProvider.getInstance(),new NotifyingEvent(Notification_type));

                //sendNotificationToFilesystem(Notification_type);

            }
        }
        //for normal notifications
        else{
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
                String User_Id=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTag();
                FirebaseNotificationService firebaseNotificationService=new FirebaseNotificationService(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                        remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),
                        User_Id);
                firebaseNotificationService.createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                        remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),
                        User_Id);
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveNotificationDataToDb(Context context , String notification_type) {
        RecievedNotificationDbtable recievedNotificationDbtable=new RecievedNotificationDbtable(context);
        recievedNotificationDbtable.open();
        recievedNotificationDbtable.insertEntry(notification_type);
        recievedNotificationDbtable.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: remoteMessage.getNotification() would be null if the app is in the background. Move your code to save data to  above the condition if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null)

Answer (score 1):

I was going wrong at the basics of firebase docs, as in the docs its clearly said that if the notification payload is there then that notification will be handled by firebase sdk and not the onMessageReceived method , so i changed the from sending both data payload and notification payload to just data payload and after that , when ever i get a notification of data payload the onMessageReceived is called and i can insert the data payload to my local db. so i changed my code to something like this

**FirebaseMsgService.class**

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if(remoteMessage.getData().get("Notification_type").equals("2")){
            String Org_Id=remoteMessage.getData().get("Org_Id");
            String Unit_Id=remoteMessage.getData().get("Unit_Id");
            String User_Id=remoteMessage.getData().get("User_Id");
            String PatientId=remoteMessage.getData().get("PatientId");
            String Notification_type=remoteMessage.getData().get("Notification_type");
            String Click_Action=remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action");
            String title=remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            String body=remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
            FirebaseNotificationService firebaseNotificationService=new FirebaseNotificationService(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        title,
                        body,
                    Click_Action,
                        User_Id,
                        Org_Id,
                        Unit_Id,
                        PatientId,
                        Notification_type);
                firebaseNotificationService.createNotification(title,
                        body,
                        User_Id);
            saveNotificationDataToDb(getApplicationContext(),Notification_type);
            BusProvider.postOnMain(BusProvider.getInstance(),new NotifyingEvent(Notification_type));

        }
}
```

*and saved to db using this method*

```
private void saveNotificationDataToDb(Context context , String notification_type) {
        RecievedNotificationDbtable recievedNotificationDbtable=new RecievedNotificationDbtable(context);
        recievedNotificationDbtable.open();
        recievedNotificationDbtable.insertEntry(notification_type);
        recievedNotificationDbtable.close();
    }
```